# HttpClient is not execute Ajax (included in PHP script) in Android

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, httpclient

I make a call to a PHP script but does not execute a piece of AJAX code. from the mobile browser runs, and from the PC browser too.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urli);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
```

My AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: /* myURL */
        dataType: 'text',  
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        success: function (data) 
        {
            if(data == 1)
            {
                alert("....");
            }
            else if (data == 0)
            {
                alert("....");
            }                               
        }                           
    });
```

What it is?

Comment: `HttpClient` is not a browser, it does not render the page, or even parse it in any way. In particular, it does not include a JavaScript parser. You need to make a `WebView` for it.

Comment: then, How I can execute the file and get json data? Thanks

Comment: Well, the most obvious way is to not fetch your PHP page that loads JavaScript to get your `myUrl` content, and instead fetch your `myUrl` content directly with `HttpClient`. That's what it does, fetches stuff. Or, if you absolutely need to execute some JavaScript, make a `WebView` as I already said.